# How to get variable from PHP file in Django(python) subprocess?

Tags: php, python, django

There is a php file like this.

```php
/* main_app/test.php */
/* I can't modify this file. */
<?
    $test_a = "this is test a.";
    $test_b = "this is test b.";
    $test_c = "this is test c.";
?>
```

and my python(views.py) code is

```py
def point_charge(request):
    import subprocess
    proc = subprocess.Popen("php /main_app/test.php", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    script_response = proc.stdout.read()
    print(script_response)
    return render(request, 'main_app/sub_pointcharge.html')
```

I want to get the value of `test_a` from `python print`.

The code I expect is like..

`print(script_response.test_a)`

> this is test a.

Can I?

thank you.

Comment: you have to display it `echo $test_a;` and then python can get it.

Comment: if you can't modify PHP then you have to read it as normal text file and search variable as normal string in text - you may need `regex` for this.